# Neural network to regress peaks in an image does not converge

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, image-processing

I am trying to predict the position (x,y)-coordinates of 16 peaks in an image.
The images look like the following:
[image]

[image]

The green dots are the true peak locations and the red crosses represent a prediction of this network:

[image]

[image]

I have tried out many configurations of differnt Kernel sizes, number of layers, less/ more dense/ convolutional layers and so on. 
I use Adam (lr=e-3) and a dropout of 20% here but I also have tried different configurations in this parameters.
I train on a batch size of 64 and aim to regress the relative coordinates (also tried with absolute coordinates).

It seems that the network is not able to train the ability of recognising a peak; instead it regresses always a kind of average.

At the moment I lack of further ideas. So I hope someone can give me a hint of what I am doing so wrong. 
Can you imagine of a reason for my problems?

Comment: Maybe pass each row at a time after cropping

Comment: How do you mean that? Like to use a recurrent network after the convolution?
Or do you mean a filter that takes a whole row?